# How to stream an audio from the internet?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to play an audio file from internet.

I've added `AudioStreamAgent` project to my solution, then in the play control in my another project:

```
if (PlayState.Playing == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
{
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause();
}
else
{
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = null;

    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri(track.url), track.Title, track.Author, null, null);
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
}
```

Is this all?

I can't hear anything, is the problem with the audio file itself or I have missed something?

**Update** in preloaded file in `AudioStreamAgent` project I see this. I think I should do something here:

```
protected override void OnBeginStreaming(AudioTrack track, AudioStreamer streamer)
{
    //TODO: Set the SetSource property of streamer to a MSS source

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

**Update 2:** I don't want my app support older versions, just OS 8.0

Comment: Have you followed [this guide from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: @NeilTurner as it's stated there, it is for playing `local media`. or I'm wrong.

Comment: My mistake, this [`AudioStreamingAgent`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb) sample from Microsoft should cover it.

Comment: thanks @NeilTurner . I saw that, but I feel it is hard and bad written. maybe because it is written to support 7.5, or I'm that stupid. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb/sourcecode?fileId=62717&pathId=948351545

Comment: have I missed something here in my codes or the problem is another thing?

Comment: It's hard to tell from that small snippet of code as there are a number of other things to do before audio will play. My suggestion would be to try and get the sample working, then try it with your audio stream. Also, if you want to support WP8 only, you can upgrade the project to WP8 - the code will almost be the same though.

Comment: What is the track.url? If that's just path to the mp3 file, then you don't need to override OnBeginStreaming

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign the track url after play button is being clicked.

The purpose of the play button in an audio player is to play the attached/pointed track. 
Not to retrieve/consume the corresponding track in the endpoint url.

Do this assignment before and somewhere else then play button clicked event.

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri(track.url), UriKind.Absolute), 
                    track.Title, 
                    track.Author, 
                    null, 
                    null)
```